# Drupal - saving created pages and page edits leads to an incorrect, blank page

Tags: drupal

Sorry if this is a bit vague...

I have a Drupal install (6.14), and when I now either create or edit a page I'm led to a blank screen once I hit 'save'. It seems to return you to a blank version of `.../node/add/page` (when creating a page), rather than taking you to the actual created node.

Also, I notice that when *editing* a page, the url contains extra elements, e.g. `/node/151/edit?destination=admin%2Fcontent%2Fnode`
 , whereas I'm pretty sure before it used to be just: `/node/151/edit`

My other Drupal sites seem to be running fine, and I've attempted to disable recently added modules, run cron, cleared cache etc. to no effect. Incidentally, when I run cron manually it *also* returns a blank page.

Please, any ideas?

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: Cheers for the link. Dang, all it was was whitespace at the end of my template.php file...